# How to get min and max range from price range slider?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery for getting min and max value from range slider but it's display nothing:

```
$j("#prise-range-input").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        grid: true,
        min: 500000,
        max: 15000000,
        from: 500000,
        to: 15000000,
        prefix: "$",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            alert(ui.values[0]);
            alert(ui.values[1]);
            $j( "#stopvalue" ).val( "$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1] );
        }
    });
```

It does not alert values can anyone tell me what wrong in this?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's console? Perhaps there is an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have checked but there is no error in my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for the IonRangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) plugin you'll see that there is no `stop` parameter in the settings object. The parameter you want to use when a range is changed is `onFinish`. This accepts a function which takes a single parameter which is an object containing the information about the slider's current state.

With that in mind, your code should be like this:

```
$j("#prise-range-input").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: 500000,
    max: 15000000,
    from: 500000,
    to: 15000000,
    prefix: "$",
    onFinish: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $j("#stopvalue").val("$" + data.from + " - $" + data.to);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b68fp7qd/)

Answer (score 0):

if you can go ahead with svg then d3 is the best option for sliders. You can refer below link to get more idea about min max slider.[D3 Min-Max Slider](https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden)